# Why does one file do so many unrelated things?

Tags: node.js

The classic nodejs hello_world.js script goes like this:

```
const http = require('http');

var s = http.createServer( function(request, response) 
                             { response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                               response.end('<html>Hello World</html>');
                             }
                         ) ;
s.listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

That file is saved in `some_random_directory` on the computer.

**1st** - the file is processed via an operating system-based command line utility:
    `C:\some_random_directory>node hello_world.js` and the hardcoded response is 'Server running at ...' This implies (to me) that the server is running.

... however ...

**2nd** - the same file is processed again but via a web browser ... does that code run again?

**3rd** - html is output to the browser

Why would one file be used in so many different ways? And isn't my goal to create a website, not a server (my apache server has been running non-stop for a decade, and I have only messed with it 4 or 5 times since; I have dozens of  websites running on it) ... I am very confused, my apologies.

Comment: I think this link will answer many of your questions: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

Answer (score 0):

The file is not re-evaluated when the browser connects to port 8124. Node does not operate like an Apache+PHP-type environment where a page load typically means parsing and executing a script for each request (and the PHP process is then killed after the request ends).

With node in this scenario, the script is parsed once and stays running in the background, but (the request handler function) is executed many times.

Comment: so if I have website_A.html (plus all of its other .html's, and .js's and .php's and .jpg's and etc) and another website_B.html .... will they run on the same server (like my apache), or will they each have their own server? And if so would they be on the same port?

Comment: You can serve whatever files you want from the same server. So instead of always responding with html, you could respond with the contents of a file if a file exists at the path the client is requesting.

Comment: I think one of the things is really confusing me is why is there a server boot-up switch (triggered from the computer's command line) and html content (triggered from the browser)  together in one file? `http.createServer(... ... response.end( [ -html content- ] )}).listen(...)`

Comment: You don't have to have your html inline if you do not want. You could put it in a file and then just write the file to the response instead (e.g. `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'}); fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(res);`)